# If the current in a conductor doubles, how would the amount of heat evolved change?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

So I came across this question in a textbook, and it says

> “If the current in a conductor increases to twice the original magnitude, the amount of heat it releases per second would increase by how much?” with the options as:
>
> a. 100%
>
> b. 200%
>
> c. 300%
>
> d. 400%

Now logically, by Joule’s Law of Heating,
H = I^2 * R * t
So H should be proportional to I^2
and hence the new heat per sec. should be 4H, keeping the answer as a 300% increase
(4H - H = 3H)

but why is the change not 100% instead?
voltage is the work done / energy spent per unit charge in taking a unit +ve test charge from infinity to a given point

so V = W/Q

hence W = QV

dividing both sides by time,
W/t = Q/t * V

W/t = VI

W = VIt
(or H = VIt)

so why is H not directly proportional to I instead of being prop. to I^2?
In the latter case, the new heat evolved would be 2H right, causing a 100% increment?

Answer (score 1):

H is a function of V too!, as I changes correspondingly V changed and hence H.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if I doubles U doubles so 2I*2U=4IU